# shell_exec() returning null on "ls"

Tags: php, linux, centos

So I have this code and I'm only trying to make a list of the saves in another directory where the php scrip is in xampp folder and the saves are to this path `/root/files/saves`:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls /root/files/saves');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why I can't get it working on a `var_dump` it seems output is null I'm really confuse it should work or I just it all wrong I need some help.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Add `2>&1` to the end of your shell command to have `STDERR` returned as well as `STDOUT`.

```
$output = shell_exec("ls /root/files/saves 2>&1");
```

Also, if the user running PHP doesn't have sufficient permissions to view the output in `/root/`, the above code will return a `Permission denied` error message.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#28994

Comment: how to permitted the user to see the output?

Comment: very precise, short and time saving solution