# PHP get string output of echo $SHELL

Tags: php, shell

How would you get the string output of the current shell in PHP?

This is what I tried

```
$output = shell_exec('echo $SHELL 2>&1');
```

but I'm getting empty output when I print it out.

$output should be a string that is something like /bin/bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell\_exec() returning null on "ls"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241305/shell-exec-returning-null-on-ls)

Comment: The code above produces no errors for me and runs just fine, returning the value I expect. I'd suggest simplifying the script include just this line along with the opening php tag and checking out the error log to see if something else failed in php which might cause nothing to be output.

Comment: @l'L'l the only (visible) anwser on that question says to add `2>&1` to the command, which OP already has. It is not a duplicate for that question.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: The permissions were more of what might be worth focusing on...

Comment: @user3226932: Do other commands return output normally?

Comment: yup, maybe I don't have permissions to use environmental variable or $SHELL is actually empty, even though when I do echo $SHELL it's there

Comment: `PHP` is generally is handled as a different user:group than you, so it's quite plausible that's the underlying reason. In your `php.ini` search for `disable_functions =`... if it's not already, try and comment it out `; disable_functions = ...`, restart apache/php and see if it works; safemode should be off.

Answer (score 1):

There is  an specific function  for getting environment  variable values
that you can use: [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

```
echo getenv('SHELL');
```